# I have a GeoTIFF that is in "WGS 84" and unts of degrees, and need to get it in units of meters. How to convert using gdal?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal

Below is the gdalinfo, I don't really know enough about GDAL to acomplish changing the units, I also don't want to change the number of cells, which seemed to happen when trying out gdalwarp. But another program I am using (BlenderGIS) needs it in meters. Anybody have a recipe?

```
Size is 2049, 2049
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-80.031969565414485,26.791587548448831)
Pixel Size = (0.000020129647277,-0.000018050547245)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Point
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=MATLAB 9.6, Mapping Toolbox 4.8
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=PACKBITS
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -80.0319696,  26.7915875) ( 80d 1'55.09"W, 26d47'29.72"N)
Lower Left  ( -80.0319696,  26.7546020) ( 80d 1'55.09"W, 26d45'16.57"N)
Upper Right ( -79.9907239,  26.7915875) ( 79d59'26.61"W, 26d47'29.72"N)
Lower Right ( -79.9907239,  26.7546020) ( 79d59'26.61"W, 26d45'16.57"N)
Center      ( -80.0113467,  26.7730948) ( 80d 0'40.85"W, 26d46'23.14"N)
Band 1 Block=208x208 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Comment: Changing from a degree-based CRS to a m-based CRS means changing the cells, since the real-world distance covered by degree varies with the latitude.

Comment: I would read the manuals, it seems to me that Blender can re-project without using other tools https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/Georeferencing-management.

Comment: Ok lets forget about not changing the number of cells. @Erik